# SQL Server HASHBYTES function returning un

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the `HASHBYTES` function in T-SQL to generate an `MD5` hash of some data, but I am getting some unexpected results, even though hashing the same data. What am I doing wrong here?

For demonstration purposes I'll create a table and insert a random guid as the 'CustomerId' and a random email address as the 'EmailAddress'. The 'ConcatHash' is a computed column which should create an MD5 hash of the two columns joined together by the pipe character. So it's easier to see whats going on I have also added a ConcatColumn so you can see what the `CONCAT_WS` is doing.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerTest
(
    CustomerId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
  , EmailAddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  , ConcatColumn AS (CONCAT_WS('|', CustomerId, EmailAddress))
  , ConcatHash AS (HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT_WS('|', CustomerId, EmailAddress))) PERSISTED
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerTest
VALUES
('8E38101D-988E-4BF1-B8F1-E8E0B8DAA891', 'a1jfapedu@adhoc-orange.com')
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.CustomerTest
```

Here is the result...
[image]

I'll now query the same data from a different table, using `CONCAT_WS` and `HASHBYTES` in exactly the same way as I did previously.

```
SELECT CustomerId
     , Email
     , CONCAT_WS('|', CustomerId, Email)                   As ConcatColumn
     , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT_WS('|', CustomerId, Email)) AS ConcatHash
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE CustomerId = '8E38101D-988E-4BF1-B8F1-E8E0B8DAA891'
```

Here is the result...
[image]

Here are the results side-by-side, and you can see the data is the same, the concatanated data is the same, yet the MD5 is different...
[image]

To save you the trouble of looking at the 'ConcatColumn' column letter by letter, I have already verified they are identical. So why is the MD5 hash different?

Comment: Hash functions operate on bytes, not characters. Both columns need to be either `NVARCHAR`, or `VARCHAR` with identical collations.

Comment: …is it collation dependant ?

Comment: Nailed it @lptr, thanks!

Comment: @lptr: Yes, because for `VARCHAR` fields, collation also determines how characters are encoded. For `NVARCHAR` fields it does not, as they are always UTF-16. (OK, technically the collations do not need to be *identical* -- `Latin1_General_CI_AS` and `Latin1_General_CI_AI` encode the same because only accent sensitivity rules are different, for example. But, say, `Japanese_` is quite different.)

Comment: ..@BrokenBad … …

Comment: ..aren’t char columns “binary in disguise”… i’ll give it a try.. thanks

Comment: @lptr Or rather, dankjewel 

Comment: @lptr: It took me a while to find a convincing example, because it's best illustrated with collations that share characters that are differently encoded (rather than entirely unsupported characters), but [here is one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dfad0536c4c9539670a3963e40ec107c). While Estonian and Latin-1 both support Æ, they encode it differently and thus hashing these strings also gives different results.

Comment: .. @JeroenMostert .. ✓ , thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varchar` and `nvarchar` columns do not produce the same hash results...

```sql
-- Setup demo data...
create table dbo.Customers1 (
  CustomerId varchar(255),
  Email varchar(255),
);
insert dbo.Customers1 (CustomerId, Email) values
  ('8E38101D-988E-4BF1-B8F1-E8E0B8DAA891', 'a1jfapedu@adhoc-orange.com');

create table dbo.Customers2 (
  CustomerId varchar(255),
  Email nvarchar(255),
);
insert dbo.Customers2 (CustomerId, Email) values
  ('8E38101D-988E-4BF1-B8F1-E8E0B8DAA891', 'a1jfapedu@adhoc-orange.com');

-- Query data...
SELECT CustomerId
     , Email
     , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT_WS('|', CustomerId, Email)) AS ConcatHash
FROM dbo.Customers1
WHERE CustomerId = '8E38101D-988E-4BF1-B8F1-E8E0B8DAA891'

SELECT CustomerId
     , Email
     , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT_WS('|', CustomerId, Email)) AS ConcatHash
FROM dbo.Customers2
WHERE CustomerId = '8E38101D-988E-4BF1-B8F1-E8E0B8DAA891'
```

Which yields...

| CustomerId | Email | ConcatHash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8E38101D-988E-4BF1-B8F1-E8E0B8DAA891 | a1jfapedu@adhoc-orange.com | 0xB3CF062CD2FAB8601A1B58E53D1F705B |

and...

| CustomerId | Email | ConcatHash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8E38101D-988E-4BF1-B8F1-E8E0B8DAA891 | a1jfapedu@adhoc-orange.com | 0xFACC935D24A15B73B4F6B864D3BA536 |